# Exporting BigQuery table from one project to another

Tags: export, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to copy a BigQuery table (Table1) stored within a Google Cloud Project (Project1) to another Google Cloud Project (Project2).  The table is on the order of TBs. What's the best way to do this so that I don't have to export the table locally? Should I export the table from Project1 to Google Cloud Storage, and then to Project2? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use bq command line tool to copy a table from one project to another. You can have a look at the following sample command

**Source:**

- **projectid**: *123456789123*
- **dataset**: *dataset1*
- **table**: *table1*

**Destination:**

- **projectid**: *0987654321098*
- **dataset**: *dataset2*
- **table**: *table2*

**Command:**

```
bq cp 123456789123:dataset1.table1 0987654321098:dataset2.table2
```

Comment: Yep. That works. But I've realized that a new BQ table is produced in dataset1 per day. I guess I have to iterate over each day's worth of data I'd like to copy...

Comment: Are you uploading the daily tables from cloud storage or is being dumped from another source like GAP?

Comment: or maybe you just want to access the table from the other project?  that can be done w/o having to make a copy...

Comment: this doesnt work cross project and different location. @KanishkaMohaia

Answer (score 5):

If you are wondering to copy the dataset from one project to another project then you can use the below command to make the transfer job:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=[PROJECT_ID] --data_source=[DATA_SOURCE] --target_dataset=[DATASET] --display_name=[NAME] --params='[PARAMETERS]'
```

where 
`PROJECT_ID` : The destination project_ID
`DATA_SOURCE` : cross_region_copy
`DATASET` : Target dataset
`NAME` : Display name of your job.
`PARAMETERS` : Source project ID, Source Dataset ID and other parameteres can be defined( overwrite destination table etc.)

You can go through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If Source and Destination in the same location  - you can just use Copy Table even between different projects

Answer (score 2):

A mass copy quick script using python

This uses the command @kanishka-mohaia gave above with the return format as json

Each each table of each dataset will be copied to the destination

This script doesn't take care of the creation of the datasets and tables

```
import json
import time
from subprocess import check_output

data_sets = json.loads(check_output("bq ls --format=json", shell=True).decode())

FROM_PROJECT = ''
TO_PROJECT = ''

for ds_item in data_sets:
    dataset = ds_item['datasetReference']['datasetId'].strip()

    tables = json.loads(
        check_output(f"bq ls --format=json {dataset}", shell=True).decode())

    for table_item in tables:
        table = table_item['tableReference']['tableId']
        print(f"Table = {dataset}.{table}")

        command = f'echo y | bq cp {FROM_PROJECT}:{dataset}.{table} ' \
                  f'{TO_PROJECT}:{dataset}.{table}'

        print(command)

        try:
            result = check_output(command, shell=True)

        except Exception as e:
            continue

        print(result)

        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution wrote in bash that allows you to insert dynamically the origin project, the destination project and limit of copy to do. You can use it in your cloud shell because gcloud dependencies are already installed.
If JQ dosen't run in your environment, perform the command to install it.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Insert origin project: " ORIGIN_PROJECT
read -p "Insert destination project: " DESTINATION_PROJECT
read -e -p "Set limit copy: " -i 100 COPYLIMIT

declare -a RESPONSE=()

if [ -z "$ORIGIN_PROJECT" ] ; then
  RESPONSE+=("ERROR: The origin project is mandatory.")
fi

if [ -z "$DESTINATION_PROJECT" ] ; then
  RESPONSE+=("ERROR: The destination project is mandatory.")
fi

if [ ${#RESPONSE[@]} -ne 0 ] ; then
  printf '%s\n' "${RESPONSE[@]}"
  exit 1;
fi

unset RESPONSE

gcloud config set project "$ORIGIN_PROJECT"

tablecopy() {
    local project=$(jq -rc .tableReference.projectId <<< $1)
    local dataset=$(jq -rc .tableReference.datasetId <<< $1)
    local dataset_table=$(jq -rc .tableReference.tableId <<< $1)

    bq cp --quiet --clone=true --force=true "$project:$dataset.$dataset_table" "$DESTINATION_PROJECT:$dataset.$dataset_table" > /dev/null

    echo "│    ├── $dataset_table " $([[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "not copied" || echo "ok")

    return 0
}

datasetcopy() {
  local project=$(jq -rc .datasetReference.projectId <<< $1)
  local dataset=$(jq -rc .datasetReference.datasetId <<< $1)
  local dataset_location=$(jq -rc .location <<< $1)

  bq --quiet --headless=true --location="$dataset_location" --project_id "$DESTINATION_PROJECT" mk "$dataset" > /dev/null

  echo "├── $dataset"

  readarray -t TABLES < <(bq ls --format=json --all=true --max_results="$COPYLIMIT" "$project:$dataset" | jq -rc .[])
  for table in "${TABLES[@]}"; do
    tablecopy "$table"
  done

  echo "│";

  return 0
}

echo "Start migration of first $COPYLIMIT datasets"

readarray -t DATASET < <(bq ls --format=json --all=true --max_results="$COPYLIMIT" | jq -rc .[])
for object in "${DATASET[@]}"; do
  datasetcopy "$object"
done

exit 0
```