# BigQuery table copy from one project to another (These use another credentials)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to copy table from SourceProject to DestProject.
SourceProject is owned by service user, and DestProject is owned by me.
I have received credentials from a service user to access SourceProject.
How can I copy table from SourceProject to DestProject?

I'm checking this question.
[Exporting BigQuery table from one project to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922939/exporting-bigquery-table-from-one-project-to-another)

And I'm tried this code.

```
source_client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=user_credentials,
    project=source_project,
)

dest_client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=my_credentials,
    project=dest_project,
)

source_dataset = source_client.dataset("source_dataset", project="source_project")
source_table_ref = source_dataset.table("source_table")

dest_dataset = dest_client.dataset("dest_dataset", project="dest_project")
dest_table_ref = dest_dataset.table("dest_table")

job = dest_client.copy_table(
    source_table_ref,
    dest_table_ref,
)  # API request

job.result()
```

but it wasn't work.(yes,of course)
returned to this message.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/dest_project/jobs: Access Denied: Dataset source_project:source_dataset: User does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset source_project:source_dataset.
```

It would be helpful if you could tell me a good way or an alternative.
thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you checked if the user you're using to write the new table has this permission?

Comment: thank you.I wasn't enough understand for permissions.I try check it.

Comment: Did you check it? Please let me know

Comment: I'm sorry to late reply.

Comment: The permissions were not set as you thought.It seemed to work if I set the table viewing permission, but in this case I couldn't adopt that method because user concern.Therefore, I changed the method to download the contents of the table and upload  to my bigquery as a dataframe.thanks.

Comment: Great! I'll post what I suggest as an answer just to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right and you set all the required information such as Project, Dataset and Table.

As we discussed in the comments, the problem for this method is that you were using the wrong credentials. In order to create a new table in BigQuery you need to have the `bigquery.tables.create` privilege in the given dataset.

If you need any further support, please let me know

Comment: thank you a lot! 
When I set the bigquery.tables.create permission on the test dataset and read the credentials, I continued to get errors against this intent, so I might ask another question about this issue.
At that time thank you again.

Comment: If you want to proceed with this solution, you can just update the question and I'll try to help you